# how to declare a String array globally.could anyone give me a simple example of it

Tags: java

i want to declare an String 1 dimensional array globally. could any one tell me how it can be performed with the help of simple example.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static String[] myBadGlobalArray = new String[mybadarrysize];
```

Answer (score 1):

...generally speaking global variables are a ***BAD*** thing.  That said, you can declare it as `public static String[] someArrayName;`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:=

```
public static String[] myArray = new String[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a class, a globally defined array could be as follows:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static String[] myArray = new String[yourSize];

}
```

However, in order to adhere to the concept of encapsulation, please use getters and setters to the array to make it accessible. It can be really easy to be lazy and declare the `String[]` as `protected` or `public`, but don't as this globalisation of variables counteracts/goes against a very important OOP principle of encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

use global public fields only if it can be final
another way use something like:

```
private String[] stringArray;


public String[] getStringArray() {
    return stringArray;
}

public void setStringArray(String[] stringArray) {
    this.stringArray = stringArray;
}
```